# powershell from Atom 1.54.0 x64

Tags: powershell

I am running `Atom 1.54.0 x64` on windows 10.
I have installed the following packages:

```
atom-terminal-powershell
platformio-ide-terminal
```

I have a powershell terminal in the bottom of the screen.
The version of powershell is `5.1.19041.610`
where.exe powershell shows this -->

```
 C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

When I launch the windows app powershell it brings up a powershell window.  The version of powershell is `7.1.1`
The where.exe shows

```
  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

I am really confused.  I am trying to get the latest version 7.1.1 to run in the atom window.  It looks like both the new version and old version are pointing at the same executable.

What would I do so that the powershell version running in the Atom editor is the latest 7.1.1 version?

I can't answer the question but I did find this.
The $pshome command at terminal shows the effective path of the executable.
For the new PowerShell app on windows it has a path like this:
>$pshome
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.PowerShell_7.1.1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe

Under Visual Studio you can pick your shell, the new powershell has an further extension of \pwsh.exe.  Was unable to get Atom to use the new powershell but visual studio allows you to select it.  I have tried various setting options but can't get it to use the new powershell..

Comment: `powershell.exe` is Windows PowerShell.  `pwsh.exe` is PowerShell (Core).  The latter defaults to `Program Files` for installation.

Comment: *"When I launch the windows app"* - right click on the start menu icon -> More -> Open File Location